# Validate user in project that is using OWIN auth middleware

Tags: asp.net, authentication, basic-authentication, owin, middleware

I am building a ASP.NET MVC 5 project that is using OWIN authentication middle-ware.

Part of the application is using Basic (or some custom) authentication. I have user name and password on the server side that I need to validate against the users database storage (this is a standard Visual Studio 2013 project with no changes).

In the past I was using membership provider to validate the user:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)
```

What do I use in case of OWIN? Should I call SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using standard mvc project with ASP.Net Identity

It uses `UserManager` for handling all identity related logic.

The method you need is:

```
 UserManager.FindAsync(userName,password);
```

In case of success it returns you a user or null otherwise.

Some great articles about ASP.Net Identity:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/25/asp-net-core-identity.aspx
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx

Some articles about owin authentication:

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown
http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux